# Работа с Video Player Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть камера, на которой скрипт и есть куб на котором должен воспроизводиться один из видеороликов (в зависимости от выбранного 3DTexta). Подскажите как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Вы не знаете как воспроизвести видео на кубе, или как выбрать текст, или как запустить конкретное видео под выбранное видео, или как камеру расположить, и т.д. и т.п. Вопрос не ясен, что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: Я уже разобрался. Сделал, чтобы по определению нужного тега объекта, он запускал Видеоплеер с Камеры, который рендерит на материал, а сам материал присвоил нужной поверхности